# Check where aliased variable is pointing to

Tags: linux, bash

I made git point to the directory where it's installed:

```
alias git = /my/file/path/libexec/git-core/git
export git = /my/file/path/libexec/git-core/git
```

I would like to double check that `git` does point to `/my/file/path/libexec/git-core/git`.

So how can I do that?
How can I get the location to which `git` is pointing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both of these commands give errors.

Use

```
alias git="/my/file/path/libexec/git-core/git"
```

To see what `git` is an alias for, use

```
alias git
```

Aliases are not exported.

Usually, files beneath a `libexec` directory are not for interactive use, but are used by other applications.  Are you sure you want to use this `git` executable?